# Error message I do not understand R renjin

Tags: java, r, renjin

I asked for a solution before, but apparently could not be helped as renjin is rather experimental still...but maybe someone could please translate the error message I get into plain English?

Maybe I can then determine if I can reasonable hope to solve this problem in a reasonable time or if I should rather abandon renjin.

Here is the message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.renjin.eval.EvalException: object 'C_hclust'    not found
```

Here is the code:

```
private void cluster()  {
    try {
        this.engine.eval("dis<-dist(myMatrix, \"binary\")");
    } catch (ScriptException ex) {System.out.println(1);
        Logger.getLogger(RWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    try {
        this.engine.eval("clus<-hclust(dis)");
    } catch (ScriptException ex) {System.out.println(3);
        Logger.getLogger(RWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        this.engine.eval("plot(clus)");
    } catch (ScriptException ex) {System.out.println(4);
        Logger.getLogger(RWorker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I did not get any of the prints, however.

Comment: Downvote for posting error message but not the code and sessionInfo that generated the error.

Comment: I am adding the code but what is a sessioninfo?

Comment: Type `sessionInfo()` at the console.

Comment: This was supposedly an R question.

Comment: I am having trouble with Renjin, which I used to be able to invoke R commands from within Java. This is why there is a Java tag and I DID mention renjin right at the beginning

Comment: Right, apparently there have been missunderstandings. How could I have posed the same question clearer?

Comment: Question seems legit to me. Note that `C_hclust` is a function in the namespace of R package `stats`, which is called by `hclust` -- an exported function in the same package. I never used renjin, but this looks like a bug, since it could resolve the symbol `hclust` but could not find the function which is called internally by `hclust`. Consider a bug report.

Comment: Shit....I feared as much. As I do have a deadline, I have to swich to JRI I guess. Ahm...not sure if I should pose a question for that  - is there a way to bundle R within a mavenproject and set the JRI path, so that the user does not need an installation of R?

Comment: @newnewbie, sorry, I can't help you with that...

Comment: Thanks anyway, was worth a try.

Comment: Care to write your answer as an answer instead of a comment so I can vote for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a letter to their mailing list - turns out it is really a bug on their part which will hopefully be fixed soon.

Answer (score 5):

C_hclust is a function from the stats package written in C but not yet included in Renjin. We are slowly integrating the C/Fortran code from the GNU R stats package as we test and expand our C/Fortran translator.

We're always looking for contributors so this might be a good mini project if you want to get involved - you can take a stab at copying the relevant sources int packages/stats/src/main/c and see if it compiles with out error.

Otherwise completing the functionality of the stats package is a priority and you can look for it in the near future!